# Android Webview crash video tag in 4.4.2 ( Xtreamer)

Tags: java, android, html, webview, html5-video

I made webview app this is java code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();

    settings. setPluginState (WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(false);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    webview.loadUrl("http://220.90.136.228:1220/001_sample/index.html");
}
```

[ Depth ]
  - index.html -> depth.html -> video.html
I used  in video.html

here is html code.

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload" src="./video/5_17-1_064.mp4">
     <track id="vtt" kink="caption" label="한국어" default ></track>
</video>
```

I can see video in Mobile(Galaxy s8), Chrome, IE,
but i can't see [Model.MV-A9]

this model os is Android 4.4.2 and every time crash in video.html
also it is not local device then i can't see log
so, i used [setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler]

this is code in onCreate

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new 
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            // TODO implement this
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert.setPositiveButton("확인", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.setMessage("테스트 메세지");
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

this code not working then i can't see log

server is IIS
I tried the following

1. Using setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler ( not working )
2. call iframe youtube ( working )
3. call small size mp4-50kb ( not working )
4. add MIME type ( not working )
5. view Internet apps on your device ( working )

help me..

Comment: its better to use iframe tag in html

Comment: using video.html in video tag with only html ??